# django localtime template filter doesn't work

Tags: django, datetime

I am use django 1.10 to display datetime. The datetime is stored in mongodb and it is always UTC without timezone info, so I need to display the date time according to machine's time zone which run django.

First, add those in settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Chongqing'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Then in views.py adds:

```
import pytz
from tzlocal import get_localzone
from django.utils import timezone
local_tz = get_localzone()
timezone.activate(local_tz)
# make datetime object and pass it to html to render
```

in template.html:

```
{% load tz %}
<table border="1">
{% for i in online %}
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>{{ i.time|localtime}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

But the datetime still UTC, even I add tzinfo to the datetime which pass into html.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Is 'i' in the template a timezone-aware datetime? Try to check the tzinfo of that datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the localtime filter to work, you need to include:

```
{% load tz %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#std:templatefilter-localtime